# Generating zoho ticket using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, zoho

I am trying to use zoho desk api in google apps script.

I am trying to genereate ticket through google script.But getting error.
Whereas if I do it in PHP its working fine.

Please find both codes for reference:

**PHP CODE which is working**

```
            $auth_token = '12345ab';//your_auth_token
            $org_id=12345; //your_organization_id

            $ticket_data=array(
                "departmentId"=>$getdepartmentid,
                "contactId"=>$getcontactid,
                "subject"=>$ticket_subject,
                "description"=>$ticket_desc,
                "priority"=>$priority,
                "status"=>$ticketstatus,
                "email"=>$contact_email,
                "classification"=>$classification,
                "channel"=>"Application"
            );

        $headers=array(
            "Authorization: $auth_token",
            "orgId: $org_id",
            "contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8",
        );

        $url="https://desk.zoho.in/api/v1/tickets";

        $ticket_data=(gettype($ticket_data)==="array")? json_encode($ticket_data):$ticket_data;

        $ch= curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$ticket_data); //convert ticket data array to json
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    


        $response= curl_exec($ch);
        $info= curl_getinfo($ch);
```

**GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT(which is not working)**

```
        var authtoken = "12345ab"; //your_auth_token
        var org_id=12345; //your_organization_id
        var department=23220000000057620; // ID of department
        var contact=23220000000066959; //ID of customer
        var subject=location_urgent_inbox_folder_name + ' /' + Name_of_file_to_be_attached;
        var description="Ticked via drive";
        var status="open";
        const ticketData = {
         subject: subject, 
         departmentId: department, // Replace this with whatever yours is.
         contactId: contact, // Replace this with whatever yours is.
         description: description,
         status: status
        };
        const zohoUrl = 'https://desk.zoho.in/api/v1/tickets';
        try {
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(zohoUrl, {
          "method": 'POST',
          "muteHttpExceptions": true,
           "headers": {
           Authorization: authtoken,
          orgId: org_id,
          contentType: 'application/json',
         },
        "payload": JSON.stringify(ticketData),
        });
        Logger.log(response.getContentText());
        const parsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        } catch (error) {
          Logger.log(error.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved,
Posting answer so that it might help someone

```
         //create ticket in zoho

        var authtoken = "abcd"; //your_auth_token
        var org_id="12345"; //your_organization_id
        var department="54321"; // ID of department in which ticket to be raised
        var contact="9999"; //ID of customer
        var subject="Ticket via google script";
        var description="Ticket via google script";
        var status="open";
        const ticketData = {
           subject: subject, 
           departmentId: department, // Replace this with whatever yours is.
           contactId: contact, // Replace this with whatever yours is.
           description: description,
           status: status
        };
        const zohoUrl = 'https://desk.zoho.in/api/v1/tickets';
        try {
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(zohoUrl, {
          "method": 'POST',
          "muteHttpExceptions": true,
          "headers": {
           Authorization: authtoken,
           orgId: org_id,
           contentType: 'application/json',
         },
         "payload": JSON.stringify(ticketData),
         });
         const parsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
         } catch (error) {
          Logger.log(error.toString());
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am looking at the right section of the right documentation (https://desk.zoho.com/DeskAPIDocument#Tickets_Createaticket), I think these are your issues:

1. Server's JSON-encoded response contains no `message` property, hence `Logger.log(result.message);` logs `undefined`. (Maybe trying logging `response.getContentText()` to see what properties are available in your case -- or refer to the API documentation.)
2. `Authorization` and `orgId` headers are missing in the request you send. (Looks like authtokens are deprecated (https://desk.zoho.com/DeskAPIDocument#Authentication) and you instead need to use OAuth 2.0 (https://desk.zoho.com/DeskAPIDocument#OauthTokens).)
3. Data needs to be sent in request's body. (You appear to be sending it in the query string.)
4. I've not read the documentation in detail but I don't see any mention of query string parameters `authtoken` and `JSONString` (CTRL+F returns no matches). So you might want to get rid of them in your code and instead follow what the documentation says.

The code below is untested and won't work (as you need to replace with your own credentials). But it should give you an idea of how you can accomplish this.

```
// See: https://desk.zoho.com/DeskAPIDocument#Tickets#Tickets_Createaticket
// Required: subject, departmentId, contactId
const ticketData = {
    subject: location_urgent_inbox_folder_name + ‘ /’ + Name_of_file_to_be_attached, // Taken from your question. Presume these are declared, valid and in scope.
    departmentId: '12345', // Replace this with whatever yours is.
    contactId: '12345', // Replace this with whatever yours is.
    description: 'Ticked via drive',
    status: 'open'
};

const zohoUrl = 'https://desk.zoho.in/api/v1/tickets';

try {
    // See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(zohoUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            orgId: '12345' // Replace this with whatever yours is.
            Authorization: 'Zoho-oauthtoken ....' // See: https://desk.zoho.com/DeskAPIDocument#OauthTokens
        },
        payload: JSON.stringify(ticketData),
    });
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    const parsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
} catch (error) {
   Logger.log(error.toString());
}
```

I've never worked with any of Zoho's APIs and haven't worked with Google Apps Script for a while, so apologies if I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi..Thank you.It helped me upto some extend..:)

Comment: But issue not resolved , I am getting error as "Insufficient Privileges to perform this operation. Contact your Administrator" while generating ticket through Google Apps Script,but Its work completely fine when I do through PHP.

Comment: @bhagyashree What does the PHP script do differently from the Google Apps Script? Maybe the PHP script is using different credentials? Another thing to try: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/insufficient-privileges-to-perform-this-operation-contact-your-administrator-26-6-2017

Comment: Hi..I have updated question & added both codes php & google apps script for reference